# Why is mcrypt_encrypt giving errors?

Tags: php

I got the code below from this site. When I run it, I get

```
Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Attempt to use an empty IV, which is NOT recommend in C:\web\apache\htdocs\dev\encrypt.php on line 7
```

What wrong am I doing here and how do I get this right?

```
//Key

$key = 'SuperSecretKey';

//To Encrypt:
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, 'I want to encrypt this', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);

//To Decrypt:
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);

echo $encrypted;
echo "<br>";
echo $decrypted;
```

Comment: Are you getting the output or only the mentioned warning..?

Comment: I'm getting the output with the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `error` its `warning`, it clearly explained in [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

> IV - Used for the initialization in CBC, CFB, OFB modes, and in some algorithms in STREAM mode. If you do not supply an IV, while it is needed for an algorithm, the function issues a warning and uses an IV with all its bytes set to "\0".

Answer (score 1):

just take a look at [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).

`IV` is the fifth parameter of `mcrypt_encrypt`.

> Used for the initialization in CBC, CFB, OFB modes, and in some algorithms in STREAM mode. If you do not supply an IV, while it is needed for an algorithm, the function issues a warning and uses an IV with all its bytes set to "\0".

Answer (score 0):

Same code with a IV (Initialization Vector) with all bytes to 0

```
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, 'I want to encrypt this', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
```